# Selectable / clickable values table values from ajax list

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently trying to make my AJAX search query as decent as possible.

And I've found a lot of different ways to do it however I want this one since it's the simplest:

```
$country_name = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['country_name']);

echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['country_name']).'\')">'.$country_name.'</li>';
        <form>
            <div class="label_div">Type a keyword : </div>
            <div class="input_container">
                <input type="text" id="testInput" onkeyup="autocomplet()">
                <ul id="country_list_id"></ul>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Ajax

```
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#country_list_id').show();
                $('#country_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
}
```

JS

```
function set_item(item) {
        // change input value
        $('#country_id').val(item);
        // hide proposition list
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
```

But I have changed a lot of code

```
// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function setvalue(item)
    $(".item").click(function()
    {
      $(".testInput").val(item));
      $('.showSearch').hide();
    })
})
```

I want this to set value into the input of which jQuery gives the list

```
echo("<a id="item"onclick="setvalue()">$rows[1]$rows[2]$rows[3]</a>");;
```

Or I want this code here

```
country_name = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['country_name']);
 echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['country_name']).'\')">'.$country_name.'</li>';
```

To be a lot more understandable. Since at the moment, it's very confusing if I want to implement it from a table. If anyone has any suggestions on how to make the code. And thanks a ton!

Comment: Where is the code for your ajax call?

Comment: I forgot to add it since it generic atm

Comment: There's no `id=country_id` in your HTML.

Comment: There is, but I didnt show it whats the point all I need to know is country_name = str_replace($_POST['keyword'], '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['country_name']);
 echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['country_name']).'\')">'.$country_name.'</li>'; into something more understandable